# How can I convert a Sublime Text syntax highlighting file to a textmate syntax for visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, textmate

I am trying to start using visual studio for my code editing instead of Sublime Text 3. In sublime text 3, I have a custom syntax file for a language I work in. I would like to be able to carry the syntax highlighting over to visual studio. I am not quite sure how I could do that without starting from scratch.

Any ideas?

In response to Matt, here is an update:

I have been trying to get it to work, but I have had no luck. It does say that textmate languages are supported:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/adding-visual-studio-editor-support-for-other-languages?view=vs-2017

It has not been working. I can not find a .vs folder on my computer (other than in projects). I created one, but it does not seem to be doing anything. I did however find an extensions folder in the appdata\local directory. I would really like to get this language supported, but I cannot find much documentation on how to do it

I have also been trying to follow this other guide using their example project as a guide:

https://gcthesoftwareengineer.com/2017/01/how-to-create-custom-syntax-highlighting-in-a-visual-studio-code-extension/

I have tried using their extension as it sits and it doesnt even work then for the language they created

Update 2:

I cannot find a .vs hidden folder in my user folder. Microsoft documentation says that you can drop a folder into the .vs/Extensions folder, but it does not exist. I am not quite sure how to proceed

Comment: Which language?

Comment: It is a language called PReS. It is pretty much non-existent.

Comment: Could you share a doc or 2? It might be possible to find a similar language

Comment: The closest language to PReS is COBOL, but the syntax is waaaay different. I am just curious as to if I am able to use my syntax file from sublime to at least start the process with making the language support for visual studio

Comment: Probably not straight forward. I was asking because I'd hoped to start you off with a different language (say COBOL) in VS but this language really is as obscure as you say, and I couldn't find anything about it :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to make a VS Code extension, but it's not so hard. Check out the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/overview) first. There's an extension generator you can use to create a skeleton project.

I made a syntax highlighter recently for a semi obscure language (Asterisk dialplan), it's on my [Github](https://github.com/peacefixation/asterisk-vscode) if you want to have a look.

The main pieces are the `package.json` and the `syntaxes\yourlanguage.tmLanguage` files. I believe Sublime uses TextMate grammars (i.e. the `tmLanguage` file) so you can probably just copy that across and craft your `package.json` and you're done.

Comment: I have been trying to get it to work, but I have had no luck. It does say that textmate languages are supported:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/adding-visual-studio-editor-support-for-other-languages?view=vs-2017

I have also been trying to follow this other guide using their example project as a guide:

https://gcthesoftwareengineer.com/2017/01/how-to-create-custom-syntax-highlighting-in-a-visual-studio-code-extension/

I have tried using their extension as it sits and it doesnt even work then for the language they created

Comment: Can you show me your language file (link github?) I'll give it a poke.

Comment: Thank you for that github link. Really helped me out on there.